# CListControl Insert Column Debug Assertion Failure

Tags: mfc, assert, listcontrol

In my application, I create a modal dialog that contains a mfc List Control. When I don't initialize any columns or items in the List Control, the dialog shows without error.  When I try to add a column to the List Control, I get the following *Debug Assertion Failed* message:

[image: Debug Assertion Failed!]

If it helps, the breakpoint is at

> _AFXCMN_INLINE int CListCtrl::InsertColumn(int nCol, const LVCOLUMN* pColumn)
>       { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (int) ::SendMessage(m_hWnd, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, nCol, (LPARAM)pColumn); }

I am trying to add the column headers with the following code in `OnInitDialog()`:

```
BOOL EventL::OnInitDialog()
{
    m_ListEventLog.InsertColumn(0, _T("Description"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 250);  //Failure happens HERE
    //m_ListEventLog.InsertColumn(0, "Description", LVCFMT_LEFT, 200, 0); //I have also tried things such as this.
    return FALSE;
}
```

I add column headers to other CListControls in my application in this way, without problems.  The modal dialog is called with the code:

```
void ListOption::OnBnClickedEventLog()
{
    EventL eventLog;
    eventLog.DoModal();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to call the default function:

```
BOOL EventL::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    m_ListEventLog.InsertColumn(0, _T("Description"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 250);  //Failure happens HERE
    //m_ListEventLog.InsertColumn(0, "Description", LVCFMT_LEFT, 200, 0); //I have also tried things such as this.
    return res; // or return FALSE;
}
```

That's why `ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd))` fails, because `m_hWnd` of ListView control is not ready. `m_hWnd` of dialog would not be ready either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, until i added `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, movies);` to

```
    void MainDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, movies);
}
```

movies - is name of the Listcontrol

```
CListCtrl movies;
```